# Странное поведение примера работы потоков из статьи [Закрыт]

Tags: c++, linux

Доброго времени суток.

Читаю статью [Программирование для Linux: потоки](http://citforum.ru/programming/unix/threads_2), в ней есть пример использование точек анулирования и макросов `pthread_cleanup_{push|pop}`. Но при выполнении этого примера на моем компьютере он работает не совсем так, как написано в статье. Там написано, что поток должен вывести на экран 4 строки и только потом завершиться, а он почему то не выводит.

Вот этот пример:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void exit_func(void * arg)
{
    free(arg);
    printf("Freed the allocated memory.\n");
}
void * thread_func(void *arg)
{    
    int i;
    void * mem;
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, NULL);
    mem = malloc(1024);
    printf("Allocated some memory.\n");
    pthread_cleanup_push(exit_func, mem);
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        sleep(1);
        printf("I'm still running!!!\n");
    }
    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
}
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{   
    pthread_t
    thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, thread_func, NULL);
    pthread_cancel(thread);
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
    printf("Done.\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

В чем может быть проблема? Прошу разъяснить.   
П.С. ОС ALTLinux 5.1. Компилирую так: `gcc main.cpp -lpthread -o threads`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Там написано, что поток должен вывести на экран 4 строки и только потом завершиться

Если там так написано - это враньё. Дело не только в скорости. Как только вы делаете поток CANCELABLE... он тут же и прерывается при вызове sleep.

Вот из [документации к Solaris](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1601/tlib-1.html#tlib-19637):

> Be careful to cancel a thread only when cancellation is safe. The pthreads standard specifies several cancellation points, including:
>
> - Programmatically, establish a thread cancellation point through a `pthread_testcancel call`.
> - Threads waiting for the occurrence of a particular condition in `pthread_cond_wait` or `pthread_cond_timedwait(3C)`.
> - Threads blocked on sigwait(2).
> - Some standard library calls. In general, these calls include functions in which threads can block. See the cancellation(5) man page for a list.

Если пойти в [cancellation(5)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1474/cancellation-5.html#cancellation-5) и почитать, то можно обнаружить в списке sleep, pwrite и write. Это будет значить, что поток будет прерываться при вызове printf или sleep и ещё во многих других случаях.

Таким образом, поведение примера полностью соответствует спецификации.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том что main выполняется быстрее чем потоки.
перед  printf("Done.n"); поставьте sleep(10);

Comment: Но это ведь испортит смысл примера. Через десять секунд нечего будет отменять :)